# How many circles in hexagonal array can I put into one circle of radius r?

Tags: geometry, number-theory

I have an hexagonal array of circles with periodicity **P**:

[image]

The diameter of one circle is **S**:

[image]

How many number of circles **n** can I fit into one big circle with radius **R**, as a function of **P**,**S** and **R** ?

[image]

n = f(P,S,R) -> f ?

Comment: I think this problem can be translated into a radius of R-S / 2 inside the circle filled with side length P + S / 2 the number of squares. Then we can be the number of squares around the square it is divided into four categories were calculated. But I did not think a good way to fill up the square method.

Comment: @Zuo would you mind to share how you came up with your solution in an answer ?

Comment: Great question !

Comment: @DoHe,In fact, I have not a rigorous and clear answer, above is my idea, but now too late I have to rest. I will continue to think, hoping to give a solution.

Comment: Packing problems are pretty difficult.  Especially when letting P > S.  When P = S, and the lattice isn't rigid, a small amount of information is known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle , or take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems.  Sorry to not be of much help, but there is a chance (not an expert on this) that this question has simply never been answered rigorously.

Comment: Your circles are not "hexagonally placed". If I turn my head at 45°, I see a "square placement".

Comment: See [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem)